# Flutter - using rxDart BehaviorSubject with Observable for global state management

Tags: flutter, observable, rxdart

I am just trying the BehaviorSubject example code from here
https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-state-management-guide/

installed rxdart and observable from pub.dev, but this line errs

```
Observable get stream$ => _counter.stream;
```

error: A value of type 'ValueStream' can't be returned from function 'stream$' because it has a return type of 'Observable'. (return_of_invalid_type at lib\models\globals.dart:54)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `Observable` class is deprecated since Dart 2.7 in which extension methods are introduced, so you have to use the normal Stream class and import RxDart plugin to get the different capabilities that RxDart offers. In case you want to combine two streams or more you can use `Rx` class. I also encourage you to use [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) plugin which deals with InheritedWidget, StreamBuilder, and Streams in a great way.

Answer (score 1):

The Fireship.io video is an excellent survey of state management options available in Flutter. Unfortunately, it is slightly out of date.

`Observable` can now be safely replaced by `Stream`

```
Observable get stream$ => _counter.stream;
```

If you need to combine streams, use `Rx.combineLatest2` instead of `Observable.combineLatest2` as the latter is now obsolete.